# SignalR maintain connection ID across different subpages

Tags: javascript, signalr

I have following problem which I can not handle mysefl:

I am wondering how to maintain ID of the client across different subpages at the server site.

Let me explain my scenario in more detailed way:

I have a pages (simple html pages with just js scripts (bootstrap, jquery and so on, no ASP involved) and one SignalR hub on the server with broadcast function to all clients. (my application is monitoring system for a industrial device, and simple functionality for a hub is only needed).

Now I have to add ability to block changing several textboxes or select items on webpages until password is entered. And I wonder how to keep information that the user is logged in on server site.

I know that every page refresh or switching to a different page which uses the same hub gives the client new connectionID.

I've found solution with custom ConnectionIDFactory method but I dont how to implement it in my project since I dont have global.asax file.

Any sugestion how to get solution for this scenario?

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a framework like Angularjs on your front end. You can then specify the routing within Angular and load the screens you need but at the same time ensure that your connection to the hub isn't being interrupted by moving to a different page. Here is an [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) of how angular achieves this. Hope this helps. It also ensures that you don't have to worry about trying to shoehorn the factory into your app.